# iOS Realm Mantle Tutorial Terminates with NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am following the [Restful API Realm Mantle tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/ios/simplifying-restful-api-use-and-data-persistence-on-ios-with-mantle-and-realm). I tried adding `sectionName` to my `ArticleModel` and that is the only apparent difference between the two to me.  I have gotten his exact [repo](https://github.com/bonzoq/RealmMantleTutorial) and ran it locally but my version ([repo here](https://github.com/raney24/RealmMantleTutorial)) throws this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary leadParagraph]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe89d250e0'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your sample code and ran it with an exception breakpoint enabled.

The problematic code appears to be here, in the file `MasterViewController.m` on line 44:

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for(ArticleModel *article in responseModel.articles){
    ArticleRealm *articleRealm = [[ArticleRealm alloc] initWithMantleModel:article];
    [realm addObject:articleRealm];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

It looks like your code is assuming that `article` is an `ArticleModel` model object, but according to Xcode's debugger, it's actually coming through as a dictionary object. As a result, the first time you try and call a property method on that object, it's throwing an exception because that method cannot her be found on a dictionary object.

I haven't played with Mantle a lot myself (It's on my to-do list!), but it looks like you'll have to manually handle serializing those article objects into `ArticleModel` objects yourself before trying to access their properties.

Good luck!